# Looking for death of Thomas James Murdin, last sighted in 1934 in Camberwell, London?

Tags: england, 20th-century, death-records, london

I am looking for the death of Thomas James Murdin who was born in Wellingborough, Northamptonshire in 1871.

In 1911 he was a tailor. His wife died in 1912, and then he seems to have lived with his children in various places. I have all the electoral registers up to 1934. The trail seems to stop there.

The last known address for him was 3 Bawdale Road, Camberwell, London, in 1934, when he was recorded on the electoral register for that year. At that time he was with his son Charles and family.

Where should I look for his death record?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE! As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about the site.  Is this the Thomas James Murdin who married Annie Chapman on 27 Jul 1890 at St. John, Walworth, Surrey, England?  If so, then I think that is useful information to [edit] into your question.  What is your 1937 residence information based on?

Comment: Apologies, he was born in 1871

Comment: I can't find him on the 1937 electoral rolls in Deptford, can you either provide a link to that record or say what the address is? I may have found him on a few electoral rolls in the early 1930s.

Comment: I cant find the link/source of the 1937 electoral register, so I would have say the latest date I have for him is 1934 electoral register where he is living in Bawdale Road with his brother Charles. In 1911 he was a tailor. His wife died in 1912, and then he seems to have lived with his children in various places. I have all the electoral registers up to 1934. The trail seems to stop there.

Answer (score 3):

As you have an address for him in 1934, I would first check the 1939 register at [FindmyPast.co.uk](http://findmypast.co.uk) for him in 1939 and also for his children -- as well as Murdin try Mardin, Martin, Murden, Merton... i.e. don't assume his name is correctly recorded (or that he was using Thomas James -- try Thomas and James and all their dimunitives; and ditto his age.  If you find him in 1939, you have a later date to start the search for his death... and if you don't you need to start searching in 1934.

[freebmd.org.uk](http://freebmd.org.uk) should be your next stop, and again you need to be creative with the search.... I can't find anything obvious but I haven't tried all the permutations and combinations. Initially I would try searching freebmd in 10 year tranches from 1934 in Deptford for the surname `m*r*n`. (And then repeat for each of his children's location -- they could have passed him around).

However, I note from your other postings elsewhere that you've tried all the above (but may not have varied your search parameters); and that his status in various of his children's marriage records is ambiguous to say the least. If you didn't have the electoral roll records, I'd suggest disbelieving some or all of his children (my great-grandfather deserted his family and was recorded as dead at most of their weddings... luckily nobody cross-checked with his death sleeping in a barn a few years later).

Another place to search would be [DeceasedOnline](http://www.deceasedonline.com) which has a wide range of burial records from local councils.  A basic search is free but you have to pay to access any records.

Comment: Thank you, I have looked in the 1939 register, I will try more of the permutations and combinations as you suggest. He is a tricky one, and as my grandfather I didn't expect him to be so elusive.